# How to initialize cluster centers for K-means in Spark MLlib?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Is there a way to initialize cluster centers while running K-Means in Spark MLlib?

I tried following :

```
model = KMeans.train(
    sc.parallelize(data), 3, maxIterations=0,
    initialModel = KMeansModel([(-1000.0,-1000.0),(5.0,5.0),(1000.0,1000.0)]))
```

`initialModel` and `setInitialModel` are not present in spark-mllib_2.10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Initial model can set in Scala since Spark 1.5+ using `setInitialModel` which takes `KMeansModel`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.{KMeans, KMeansModel}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

val data = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    "[0.0, 0.0]", "[1.0, 1.0]", "[9.0, 8.0]", "[8.0,  9.0]"
)).map(Vectors.parse(_))

val initialModel = new KMeansModel(
   Array("[0.6,  0.6]", "[8.0,  8.0]").map(Vectors.parse(_))
)

val model = new KMeans()
  .setInitialModel(initialModel)
  .setK(2)
  .run(data)
```

and PySpark 1.6+ using `initialModel` parameter to `train` method:

```py
from pyspark.mllib.clustering import KMeansModel, KMeans
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors

data = sc.parallelize([
    "[0.0, 0.0]", "[1.0, 1.0]", "[9.0, 8.0]", "[8.0,  9.0]"
]).map(Vectors.parse)

initialModel = KMeansModel([
    Vectors.parse(v) for v in ["[0.6,  0.6]", "[8.0,  8.0]"]])
model = KMeans.train(data, 2, initialModel=initialModel)
```

If any of these methods doesn't work it means that you're using an earlier version of Spark.

Comment: My build.sbt has following :
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2" % "provided" withSources() withJavadoc(),
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.5.2" % "provided" withSources() withJavadoc(),

Yet I am unable to find setInitialModel while coding on intelliJ

Comment: Hi, I am trying to implement the same using pyspark but I am not giving the cluster centers as you did. I am extracting them from a previous trained model using this command centerVectors = preModel.clusterCenters(). The problem is in the format of those points or cluster centers. Can you please specify the correct type of the cluster centers. Are they string of many lists ? I have attached the code below. it's not working out for me.

Comment: centersList = []
for center in centerVectors:  
  centersList = [center.tolist()] + centersList

Comment: initialModel = KMeansModel([Vectors.parse(str(len(v), str(v))) for v in centersList])