# Initialize Cluster Centers in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to do something very similar to this question:
[How to initialize cluster centers for K-means in Spark MLlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35426240/how-to-initialize-cluster-centers-for-k-means-in-spark-mllib)
However, I don't totally understand the solution. When I try to add more centroids, I get an error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: mismatched cluster count`

I use

```
val initialModel = new KMeansModel(
   Array("[0.6,  0.6, 5.0]", "[8.0,  8.0, 1.0]", "[11,  9.0, 7.0]").map(Vectors.parse(_))
)
val model = new KMeans()
  .setInitialModel(initialModel)
  .setK(3)
  .run(data)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize cluster centers for K-means in Spark MLlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35426240/how-to-initialize-cluster-centers-for-k-means-in-spark-mllib)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, KMeans set K to 2. It's as easy as setting K before setting the initial model (KMeansModel.k and KMeans.k must coincide).

```
val initialModel = new KMeansModel(
   Array("[0.6,  0.6, 5.0]", "[8.0,  8.0, 1.0]", "[11,  9.0, 7.0]").map(Vectors.parse(_))
)

val model = new KMeans()
  .setK(3)
  .setInitialModel(initialModel)
  .run(data)
```